# Can I remove this cross piece in my attic?

Tags: attic, roofing

Every time I go up into the loft, I whack my head on the lower crossbeam.

I can't see any purpose in it; it is attached with a single nail either side and no actual joints, so presumably it can't be holding much strain?

Can I remove it?

[image]

Comment: Something that non-structural may have been put in by a previous owner as a place to hang things for storage. Empty plant hanging baskets during the winter, ... . If they could hang and remove items without climbing up to the attic floor it would have made life easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a hand-framed roof system, so it's difficult to pinpoint what the intention of that board was, but it doesn't appear to be important for a couple reasons:

- It's only connected to two of the struts. That doesn't accomplish much.
- It's very near the lateral run against the rafters.
- It doesn't appear very well fastened. From here I see just one nail in the near end.

My wild guess is that it was placed as a safety rail of sorts to reduce the chance of someone stepping through the access opening. I'd go ahead and remove it, but watch for movement in the roof framing in the future.

Comment: Where "watch for movement" = 1) take measurements of all spacing before removing it. 2) take duplicate measurements after removing it. 3) write down these measurements. 4) take updated measurements 1x/week for the first 4-8 weeks. 5) take monthly measurements for 12 months following. If there's been no movement in a year, you're _probably_ good, but repeating the measurements every 6 months after that isn't going to hurt.

Comment: That seems like overkill. I might take a photo beforehand and call it good. :)

Comment: What can I say, I'm into overkill. Plus the roof's over my head, not yours. :D

Answer (score 3):

It was probably put there as a temporary hold for the struts going down from roof to loft 'floor', to stop them floating and twisting. Although it looks like it didn't work too well on the one closest to camera. I'd make a bracket up so they are more secure against the rafters, and go ahead. As often the case, if in doubt, a structural engineer will be a good guide.

Comment: I've marked isherwood's answer as the solution because it's a bit more detailed but I will take on board the bracket idea! The near strut looks fine in the flesh, I think it's a wide angle lens effect making it look twisted

Comment: I'd love it if the dver would bother to explain why it's worthy!

Comment: I voted this answer down. I simply think it's wrong. I doubt your proposed purpose is right, and "a bracket" is a vague and unnecessary step.